# how to send user and passowrd in api using request.fields and http.MultipartRequest in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart, request, multipart

the postman give me a code it's first time to see the same, and it dont work with me here is the postman code

```
var headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json'
};
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse('https://***.com/api'));
request.fields.addAll({
  'action[]': 'Auth',
  'action[]': 'Login',
  'mobile': '1234',
  'password': '1234'
});

request.headers.addAll(headers);

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
}
else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
}
```

its return "Internal Server Error", I tried to edit the code

```
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var item =
          JsonDecoder().convert("${await response.stream.bytesToString()}");
      print("item $item");
      return response.statusCode;
    } else {
      print("response.statusCode ${response.statusCode}");

      print("response.reasonPhrase :=> ${response.reasonPhrase}");
      return response.statusCode;
    }
```

and it print

```
I/flutter (28103): response.statusCode 500
I/flutter (28103): response.reasonPhrase :=> Internal Server Error
```

I contact the server programers and they told me the server work well and the website reseave the data well, please help

Comment: instead of multipart, you can use http package. It is easy to use.

Comment: - first, you can check backend API using postman or insomnia. - if you don't need to upload a file, you can use HTTP package. - not sure why you are using the same keyword again. action[]

Comment: the postman give me  this code, so in http how to send  'action[]': 'Auth',
  'action[]': 'Login',
  'mobile': '1234',
  'password': '1234'